# Android Mockito kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property dataManager has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito, dagger-2, mvp

I constantly get `kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property xxx has not been initialized` in my Mockito test. But the app works just fine. Note: I don't want to inject presenter into activity. Thanks in advance!

Here's my Activity:

```
class CreateAccountActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CreateAccountView {

private var presenter: CreateAccountPresenter? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_account)
    presenter = CreateAccountPresenter()
    ((application) as CariumApp).getDaggerComponent().inject(presenter!!)

    presenter?.attachView(this)
}
```

And here's my Presenter:

```
class CreateAccountPresenter {
private var view: CreateAccountView? = null

@Inject
lateinit var dataManager: DataManager

fun attachView(view: CreateAccountView) {
    this.view = view

    dataManager.getServiceDocuments(true, object : GetServiceDocumentsListener { 
       // ...
    })
}
```

Here's my DataManager:

```
interface DataManager {
    fun getServiceDocuments(latest: Boolean, listener: GetServiceDocumentsListener)
}
```

and AppDataManager:

```
Singleton
class AppDataManager @Inject constructor(context: Context) : DataManager {
// ...
}
```

and finally my test that's failing:

```
class CreateAccountPresenterTest {

val mockDataManager: DataManager = mock()

val mockCreateAccountView: CreateAccountView = mock()

private val createAccountPresenter = CreateAccountPresenter()

@Test
fun getServiceDocuments() {
    doAnswer {
        val args = it.arguments
        (args[1] as GetServiceDocumentsListener).onError()
        null
    }.`when`(mockDataManager).getServiceDocuments(Mockito.anyBoolean(), anyOrNull())

    createAccountPresenter.attachView(mockCreateAccountView)

    verify(mockCreateAccountView).hideLoadingDialog()
}
}
```

gradle file:

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.22.0'
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.22.0"
testImplementation "com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.0.0-RC1"
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.16'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.16'
```

My module class:

```
@Module
open class MyModule(private var context: Context) {

@Provides
open fun provideContext(): Context {
    return context
}

@Provides
@Singleton
internal fun provideDataManager(appDataManager: AppDataManager): DataManager {
    return appDataManager
}
}
```

Actual error is ***kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property dataManager has not been initialized***

Answer (score 2):

You are not assigning your mock to the field. Assign it in your test method. Before calling `attachView()`

```
createAccountPresenter.dataManager = mockDataManager
```

Comment: I don't think it's gonna help, DI should work a bit different

Comment: Did you try it? If you want DI to work in tests you will have to create test modules with mocked objects and also to have a `TestApplication`.  What you can do is have a separate `package private` constructors which takes in a `DataManager` instance. You can use it only for tests. But its the same as what i have suggested in my answer.

Comment: I think you are wrong. I don't need a test modules for this kind of test!

Comment: If you want dagger to inject stuff you do. But please prove me that i'm wrong. Don't just think. I would be really interested to know if you find another way

Comment: sorry Rajitha, maybe we are talking about two different things. I don't need dagger to Inject things, I need to mock Dagger injected objects using Mockito, that's it. Actually I got it working with Presenter's constructor injection, but it's not what I really need.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you have `DataManager` `@Provides` method? Dagger recognizes `@Inject` constructor inside `AppDataManager` but cannot recognize it as interface. Create Module for Dagger that is abstract and uses `@Binds`

https://proandroiddev.com/dagger-2-annotations-binds-contributesandroidinjector-a09e6a57758f

Comment: thanks for the reply Tuby! I have updated my question with Module class. Looking at @Binds annotation

Comment: Ok you already have it then. @Binds is nothing more than you have in your current Module

Comment: I can't figure out how to replace `@Inject
    lateinit var dataManager: DataManager` in my Presenter with mocked object

Comment: I would switch to constructor injection

Comment: then I will need to Inject Presenter into Activity what I don't really want to do

Comment: I use to do some complicated stuff like extending existing dagger component and adding TestModules with mocked objects